# UI not updating on "page load" in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a project using Angular 1.4.3.  On one of the pages, I'm selecting a value from a grid and it then goes to show the details of that record on another page.  During the "page load" of the details page, I'm going out to a service and grabbing the value from the database.  I'm able to see the results come back from the database and service, and then populate the appropriate variable, but the UI isn't updated with the appropriate values.  Doing some research, the use of $scope.$apply() and the $timeout() function were mentioned, but I'm not running into any success with that.

Is there anything that should be done to try to make the UI refresh during the page load in Angular?

Comment: The UI will update automatically if the data is being set on the controller in a standard way. Try and provide a jsfiddle or some other working sample - there is no way to determine the error with the given description

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you got two controllers:

```
        var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.name = 'World';
          $scope.another = 'AnotherWorld';
        });

        app.controller('AnotherCtrl', function($scope) {
        });
```

and template:

```
        <div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
              <p>{{name}}</p>
              <div ng-controller="AnotherCtrl">
            <p>{{name}}</p>
            <p>{{another}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

name and another are inherited from parent into child scope, which you should see updated promptly on the template.

Now introduce a service:

```
        app.service('OnlyAService', function($q, $timeout){
             return {
               getNewValue: getNewValue
             }

             function getNewValue() {
             var deferred = $q.defer();
             $timeout(function(){
               deferred.resolve({name: 'NewCrapReplacedWorld', another: 'NewCrapReplacedAnotherWorld'});
             }, 2000);

             return deferred.promise;
           }
        });
```

Inject the service into AnotherCtrl, update another and name

```
        app.controller('AnotherCtrl', function($scope, OnlyAService) {
          OnlyAService.getNewValue().then(function(data){
             $scope.another = data.another;
             $scope.name = data.name;

          });
        });
```

You would see that another and name within the AnotherCtrl on the template changes, but not the one for the parent.  It will never change.  One solution is to use $scope.$parent.name = data.name.

The so-called scope soup might be the reason for your issue, maybe.  There are other ways of fixing it.  Without code, it's a very wide area to speculate.